# Flutter : How to use setter to reset value

Tags: flutter, logout, setter

I have variable called to totalQuantity in provider:

```
get totalQuantity => total_quantity();

  total_quantity() {
    var totalQty = 0;
    for (var x in myCart) {
      totalQty += (x.quantity);
    }
    return totalQty;
  }
```

I use it in the app bar:

```
child: Text('${prod.totalQuantity}',
```

I have a logout function I want when I pressed on it to reset totalQuantity, I guess using setter for that in provider, but I don't know how to do that.

```
IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  prod.clear_myCart();
                  loginProd.log_out();
                            // ----------------- I want to reset it here
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake ,I forgot to add listen notifier

```
void clear_myCart() {
    myCart.clear();
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

after I add it ,it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to return `totalQuantity` to the original (empty) value, so lets have a look at where it gets its value from:
Your `total_quantity()` function depends on one variable, `myCart`.
So, if you clear `myCart` in `prod.clear_myCart();`, the quantity should also be updated accordingly.

Now, what your code does not show is how the value change of `myCart` is being handled in your code;
I am speculating here because your code snippets don't provide enough information, but your `ChangeNotifier` might just not call `notifyListeners()` when you call `prod.clear_myCart();` (See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple).